# Angularfire2 attach more data to user collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am creating an app where users can create groups. group collection is stored inside each user, and if owner of the group ads members corresponding users id and role only saved inside group collection. So when owner visits group members i wish to show full info of users which is in another collection out side groups.

these are two collections in my firestore database

```
this.afs.collection(`users/${ownerId}/groups/${gid}/users`)
this.afs.doc(`users/${ownerId}`) //full user data
```

here is how  i access users in my services

```
getGroupUsers(gid, ownerId) {
return this.afs.collection(`users/${ownerId}/groups/${gid}/users`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();
      const userId = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { userId, ...data };
    })
    )
  );
}
```

here `userId` is each users unique id and i wish to add more data to `...data` object. I tried many ways and failed, here is what i try to achive

```
getGroupUsers(gid, ownerId) {
return this.afs.collection(`users/${ownerId}/groups/${gid}/users`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const userId = a.payload.doc.id;
    //return { userId, ...data };
    return this.afs.doc(`users/${userId}`).valueChanges().pipe(
      map(userData => {
        return {userId, ...data, ...userData}
      })
    )
  })
  )
);
}
```

I use `angular 8.1.2` and `Rxjs 6.4.0`. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but you can use a combination of [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) or [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) and [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html). `switchMap` to switch to the inner observable and `combineLatest` to perform the nested requests.

```ts
getGroupUsers(gid, ownerId) {
  return this.afs.collection(`users/${ownerId}/groups/${gid}/users`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    switchMap(actions => combineLatest(
      actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const userId = a.payload.doc.id;
        return this.afs.doc(`users/${userId}`).valueChanges().pipe(
          map(userData => {
            return { userId, ...data, ...userData }
          })
        )
      })
    ))
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it throws this error `Uncaught TypeError: You provided 'function (source) { return source.lift.call(from_1.from([source].concat(observables)), new combineLatest_1.CombineLatestOperator(project)); }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
`

Comment: Hmm... just tested this code now on on a firebase project, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming. i found the issue is with `combineLatest` import. i changed `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';` to `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';`. Now its works fine. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh yeah, I could have added the imports for clarity, but glad you figured it :) And yes, you are very welcome!